# DSE 5.0 Custom Codecs in Scala - Intellij does not compile

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to write a custom codec to convert Cassandra columns of type `timestamp` to `org.joda.time.DateTime`.

I am building my project with sbt versions 0.13.13.

I wrote a test that serializes and deserializes a `DateTime` object. When I run the test via the command line with `sbt "test:testOnly *DateTimeCodecTest"`, the project builds and the test passes.

However, if I try to build the project inside Intellij, I receive the following error:

```
Error:(17, 22) overloaded method constructor TypeCodec with alternatives:
  (x$1: com.datastax.driver.core.DataType,x$2: shade.com.datastax.spark.connector.google.common.reflect.TypeToken[org.joda.time.DateTime])com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec[org.joda.time.DateTime] <and>
  (x$1: com.datastax.driver.core.DataType,x$2: Class[org.joda.time.DateTime])com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec[org.joda.time.DateTime]
 cannot be applied to (com.datastax.driver.core.DataType, com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken[org.joda.time.DateTime])
object DateTimeCodec extends TypeCodec[DateTime](DataType.timestamp(), TypeToken.of(classOf[DateTime]).wrap()) {
```

Here is the codec:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

import com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException
import com.datastax.driver.core.{ DataType, ProtocolVersion, TypeCodec }
import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken
import org.joda.time.{ DateTime, DateTimeZone }

/**
 * Provides serialization between Cassandra types and org.joda.time.DateTime
 *
 * Reference for writing custom codecs in Scala:
 *   https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/writing-scala-codecs-for-the-java-driver
 */
object DateTimeCodec extends TypeCodec[DateTime](DataType.timestamp(), TypeToken.of(classOf[DateTime]).wrap()) {

  override def serialize(value: DateTime, protocolVersion: ProtocolVersion): ByteBuffer = {
    if (value == null) return null

    val millis: Long = value.getMillis

    TypeCodec.bigint().serializeNoBoxing(millis, protocolVersion)
  }

  override def deserialize(bytes: ByteBuffer, protocolVersion: ProtocolVersion): DateTime = {
    val millis: Long = TypeCodec.bigint().deserializeNoBoxing(bytes, protocolVersion)
    new DateTime(millis).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)
  }

  // Do we need a formatter?
  override def format(value: DateTime): String = value.getMillis.toString

  // Do we need a formatter?
  override def parse(value: String): DateTime = {
    try {
      if (value == null ||
        value.isEmpty ||
        value.equalsIgnoreCase("NULL")) throw new Exception("Cannot produce a DateTime object from empty value")
      // Do we need a formatter?
      else new DateTime(value)
    } catch {
      // TODO: Determine the more specific exception that would be thrown in this case
      case e: Exception =>
        throw new InvalidTypeException(s"""Cannot parse DateTime from "$value"""", e)
    }
  }

}
```

and here is the test:

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.ProtocolVersion
import org.joda.time.{ DateTime, DateTimeZone }
import org.scalatest.FunSpec

class DateTimeCodecTest extends FunSpec {

  describe("Serialization") {
    it("should serialize between Cassandra types and org.joda.time.DateTime") {
      val now = new DateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)

      val result = DateTimeCodec.deserialize(
        // TODO: Verify correct ProtocolVersion for DSE 5.0
        DateTimeCodec.serialize(now, ProtocolVersion.V4), ProtocolVersion.V4
      )

      assertResult(now)(result)
    }
  }
}
```

I make extensive use of the debugger within Intellij as well as the ability to quickly run a single test using some hotkeys. Losing the ability to compile within the IDE is *almost* as bad as losing the ability to compile at all. Any help would be appreciated, and I am more than happy to provide any additional information about my project // environment if anyone needs it.

**Edit, update:**
The project compiles within IntelliJ if I provide an instance of `com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken` as opposed to `shade.com.datastax.spark.connector.google.common.reflect.TypeToken`.

However, this breaks the build within sbt.

Comment: You must create a default constructor for DateTimeCodec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue.

The issue stemmed from conflicting versions of `spark-cassandra-connector` on the classpath. Both shaded and unshaded versions of the dependency were on the classpath, and removing the shaded dependency fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a default constructor for DateTimeCodec.